# JS time calculation add and set value

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a page to easily calculate when I could go home from work. The page should set a start date when loaded. That way I don't have to know when I started working and just open my browser. Then by clicking one of the buttons it should just add some hours.

The example is one of the many things I've tried already. But this one is close I think. Any suggestions are welcome. I didn't include jquery because of the small scale this has.

```js
function reset() {
  var date = new Date();
  var hour = date.getHours(),
    min = date.getMinutes();

  hour = (hour < 10 ? "0" : "") + hour;
  min = (min < 10 ? "0" : "") + min;

  var timestamp = hour + ":" + min;

  document.getElementById("start_time").value = timestamp;
}

function add_time_76() {
  var start = document.getElementById("start_time").value;
  document.getElementById("end_time").value = start + 7, 6;
}

function getTotal() {
  var start = document.getElementById("start_time").value;
  var end = document.getElementById("end_time").value;
  document.getElementById("total").value = end - start;
}
```

```html
<body onload="reset()">

  <p>Start time: <input name="start_time" type="time" /></p>
  <p>Time to go home: <input name="end_time" type="time" /></p>
  <p>Total hours: <input type="text" name="total" readonly></p>


  <button onclick="add_time_76()">Add 7,6h</button>
  <button onclick="add_time_8()">Add 8h</button>
  <br><br>
  <button onclick="getTotal()">Calculate Total</button>
  <br><br>
  <button onclick="reset()">Reset</button>

</body>
```

The time fields aren't getting populated when I want them to be.

Comment: Check your console: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null
    at reset ((index):16)
    at onload ((index):4)

Comment: Always try to use developer tools and check the console if you have any errors before actually jumping to SO.

Comment: You're using `document.getElementById` but not setting any element IDs anywhere

Comment: As a side point, you don't need to re-invent the wheel. Look up add/subtract time from Date.

Comment: I knew it would be something stupid... thanks got it to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a id to your inputs.

```
<p>Start time: <input id="start_time" name="start_time" type="time" /></p>
<p>Time to go home: <input id="end_time" name="end_time" type="time" /></p>
<p>Total hours: <input id="total" type="text" name="total" readonly></p>
```